# Getting a conditional message out of a foreach loop

Tags: php

I'm displaying all the posts in the category that have a valid date as follows -

```
<?php $blog = $pages->find('posts');
     foreach($blog->children() as $blogpost): ?>
     <?php if ($blogpost->title() <= $latest && $blogpost->category == $thisCat): ?>
              //HTML for displaying post goes here
         <?php endif ?>
     <?php end foreach ?>
```

That works fine when those posts validate my condition, and displays nothing if it doesn't. What I want to do is display an error message (like 'there are no posts here') when there are no posts that pass the condition. I can't just do a simple `else` condition in that `if` query because it's inside the `foreach` loop. I can't take the `if` query out of the `foreach` loop because it relies on a variable that is defined as part of it (`$blogpost`).

Kind of stuck in this catch 22... Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about...

```
 <?php
 $blog = $pages->find('posts');
 $found_something = false;
 foreach($blog->children() as $blogpost) {
   if ($blogpost->title() <= $latest && $blogpost->category == $thisCat) {
      $found_something = true;
      //HTML for displaying post goes here
   }
 }
 if(!$found_something) {
   // display error message
 }
 ?>
```

By the way, is there a specific reason why you're using the [alternative PHP syntax](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php)?

Comment: Amazing, thanks very much. This worked a treat!

I'm using the alternative syntax because there's bunch of HTML in that foreach loop, and it's more readable (and I think slightly better performance wise) to have it as HTML rather than a string that is echoed.

Answer (score 0):

I'd create a counter variable which increments each time when you display a post.

```
<?php $blog = $pages->find('posts');
      $displayedPosts = 0;
     foreach($blog->children() as $blogpost): ?>
     <?php if ($blogpost->title() <= $latest && $blogpost->category == $thisCat):
             $displayedPosts++; ?>
              //HTML for displaying post goes here
         <?php endif ?>
     <?php end foreach ?>
<?php
  if ($displayedPosts == 0) {
    echo 'ERROR!';
  }
?>
```

Using a boolean variable (as tmh did) is probably better in this case unless you want to count the posts.

Answer (score 0):

Just count your posts , if it's 0 display just the message , else execute foreach loop :

```
  <?php $blog = $pages->find('posts');

 if(count($blog->children())==0){ echo 'No post Here'; } 

 else{

   foreach($blog->children() as $blogpost): ?>
   <?php if ($blogpost->title() <= $latest && $blogpost->category == $thisCat): ?>
          //HTML for displaying post goes here
       <?php endif ?>
   <?php end foreach ?>

<?php } ?>
```

Comment: This doesn't work because that counts the posts which don't pass the condition as well.

Comment: did you tried it ? It should work ,foreach will be executed only if there is one or more posts